# How to make picture at bottom and centered in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, center

Using bootstrap 3 i have some issues that i have tried to fix.
I need picture to be always centered inside element and bootom of element?

Here is what i have

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<a class="jumper" style="position:absolute; bottom:0;"><img src="mypicture"></a>
</div>'
```

this way i have made it to stay always at left corner, but ho to make it to be centered in parent element also?

I have tried text-centered, center-block. But i have no luck?

**SOLUTION, BUT NO BOOTSTRAP**

*css*

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="container" align="center">
    <a class="jumper" style="position:absolute; bottom:0;"><img src="mypicture"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer would be better with an explanation of why this would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" align="center">
<a class="jumper" style="position:absolute; top:0;left:0;right:0"><img src="mypicture"></a>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?